# CSS: dynamic Icon Window

Tags: css

I am trying to make the site look sorta like a desktop app...It will sorta resemble Program Manager from windows 3.1 except i need the icon groups to resize and tile depending on the number of icons i have and how much space they need. they don't need to take up 100% of the space inside, but at leastmake 2 - 3 columns and fill in the empty spaces AND they do n o need to be fixed widths.

What I am getting
[image]

What I am trying for

[image]

```css
body 
{
 padding: 5px;
 height: 99%;
 margin: 0;
}
#mainWin
{
 border-color: Black;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-style: Solid;
 border-radius: 10px;
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
#titleBar
{
 background-color: blue;
 border-top-left-radius: 9px;
 border-top-right-radius: 9px;
 text-align: center;
 height: 17px;
 padding: 2px;
 color: white;
 display: table-cell;
 width: 100%;
}
#Wrapper 
{
 border: solid black 1px;
 display: table-row;
 height: 100%;
 padding:5px
}
#cellWrapper
{
 padding: 5px;
 display: table-cell;
}
#statusBar
{
 background-color: lightgray;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 9px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;
 height: 17px;
 padding: 2px 2px 2px 10px;
 color: black;
 display: table-cell;
}

.Window
{
 border-color: Black;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-style: Solid;
 border-radius: 10px;
 display: table;
 width: 45%;
 margin:5px;
}
.titleWindow
{
 background-color: blue;
 border-top-left-radius: 9px;
 border-top-right-radius: 9px;
 text-align: center;
 height: 17px;
 padding: 2px;
 color: white;
 display: table-cell;
 width: 100%;
}
.wrapWindow 
{
 border: solid black 1px;
 display: table-row;
 height: 100%;
 padding:5px
}
.wrapcellWindow
{
 padding: 5px;
 display: table-cell;
}
.stausWindow
{
 background-color: lightgray;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 9px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;
 height: 17px;
 padding: 2px 2px 2px 10px;
 color: black;
 display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <title></title>
 <link href="/CSS/Service.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1">
 <div id="mainWin">
  <div id="titleBar">
   Consumer Lawncare Inventory Tracking System
  </div>
  <div id="Wrapper">
   <div id="cellWrapper">
    <div class="Window">
     <div class="titleWindow">
      Some Window
     </div>
     <div class="wrapWindow">
      <div class="wrapcellWindow">
       The inside it 1 <br />qweqweq<br />qweq<br />qwe<br />qweqw<br /><br />qweqweqwe<br />qweqweqwe<br />qweqweq<br />weqweq
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="stausWindow">
      Some Status Bar
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Window">
     <div class="titleWindow">
      Some Window
     </div>
     <div class="wrapWindow">
      <div class="wrapcellWindow">
       The inside it 2 
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="stausWindow">
      Some Status Bar
     </div>
    </div>                <div class="Window">
     <div class="titleWindow">
      Some Window
     </div>
     <div class="wrapWindow">
      <div class="wrapcellWindow">
       The inside it 3 
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="stausWindow">
      Some Status Bar
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="statusBar">
   Ready
  </div>
 <div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `float: left;` to `.window`

```css
body 
{
 padding: 5px;
 height: 99%;
 margin: 0;
}
#mainWin
{
 border-color: Black;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-style: Solid;
 border-radius: 10px;
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
#titleBar
{
 background-color: blue;
 border-top-left-radius: 9px;
 border-top-right-radius: 9px;
 text-align: center;
 height: 17px;
 padding: 2px;
 color: white;
 display: table-cell;
 width: 100%;
}
#Wrapper 
{
 border: solid black 1px;
 display: table-row;
 height: 100%;
 padding:5px
}
#cellWrapper
{
 padding: 5px;
 display: table-cell;
}
#statusBar
{
 background-color: lightgray;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 9px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;
 height: 17px;
 padding: 2px 2px 2px 10px;
 color: black;
 display: table-cell;
}

.Window
{
 border-color: Black;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-style: Solid;
 border-radius: 10px;
 display: table;
 width: 45%;
 margin:5px;
    float: left; <!---here--->
}
.titleWindow
{
 background-color: blue;
 border-top-left-radius: 9px;
 border-top-right-radius: 9px;
 text-align: center;
 height: 17px;
 padding: 2px;
 color: white;
 display: table-cell;
 width: 100%;
}
.wrapWindow 
{
 border: solid black 1px;
 display: table-row;
 height: 100%;
 padding:5px
}
.wrapcellWindow
{
 padding: 5px;
 display: table-cell;
}
.stausWindow
{
 background-color: lightgray;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 9px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;
 height: 17px;
 padding: 2px 2px 2px 10px;
 color: black;
 display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <title></title>
 <link href="/CSS/Service.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1">
 <div id="mainWin">
  <div id="titleBar">
   Consumer Lawncare Inventory Tracking System
  </div>
  <div id="Wrapper">
   <div id="cellWrapper">
    <div class="Window">
     <div class="titleWindow">
      Some Window
     </div>
     <div class="wrapWindow">
      <div class="wrapcellWindow">
       The inside it 1 <br />qweqweq<br />qweq<br />qwe<br />qweqw<br /><br />qweqweqwe<br />qweqweqwe<br />qweqweq<br />weqweq
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="stausWindow">
      Some Status Bar
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Window">
     <div class="titleWindow">
      Some Window
     </div>
     <div class="wrapWindow">
      <div class="wrapcellWindow">
       The inside it 2 
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="stausWindow">
      Some Status Bar
     </div>
    </div>                <div class="Window">
     <div class="titleWindow">
      Some Window
     </div>
     <div class="wrapWindow">
      <div class="wrapcellWindow">
       The inside it 3 
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="stausWindow">
      Some Status Bar
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="statusBar">
   Ready
  </div>
 <div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added new class for right side containers

```
.Window
{
    border-color: Black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: Solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: table;
    float:left;
    width: 45%;
    margin:5px;
}


.Window-side
{
    border-color: Black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: Solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float:right;
    width: 45%;
    margin:5px;
}
```

Removed unnecessary `table-cell` property from stausWindow and wrap classes.

**PREVIEW**

http://output.jsbin.com/xalozotuxo/2/

**CODE**

http://output.jsbin.com/xalozotuxo/2/edit